# Troubles with printing functions in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

My  exercise  is  to  Insert  Elements  in  BSTree  and   Find  the  Max  element  of  it. After  I  did  that, It  is  not   printing  anything  and  always  return  0. I tried with Print Function but it was same i don't know the reason .  Please help. Thanks  in  advance .............................................................................................................................................................

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct BstNode {
    int data;
    BstNode *left;
    BstNode *right;

    BstNode(int data1, BstNode *left1 = nullptr, BstNode *right1 = nullptr) : data(data1), left(left1), right(right1) {}

    ~BstNode() {}

};

class BinTree {
private:
    BstNode *root;
public:
    BinTree() : root(NULL) {}

    ~BinTree() {}

    BstNode *Insert(int data, BstNode *root) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            root = new BstNode(data);
            return root;
        }
        while (data <= root->data) {
            if (root->left == NULL) {
                root->left = new BstNode(data);
            }
            Insert(data, root->left);
        }
        while (data <= root->data) {
            if (root->right == NULL) {
                root->right = new BstNode(data);
            }
            Insert(data, root->right);
        }
    }

    int FindMax() {
        MaxHelper(root);
    }

    int MaxHelper(BstNode *root) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            cout << "List is empty  ";
            return -1;
        } else if (root->right != NULL) {
            root = root->right;
        }
        return root->data;
    }

    void Preorder(BstNode *root) { //DLR
        if (root == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        cout << root->data;
        Preorder(root->left);
        Preorder(root->right);
    }


};

BstNode *root = new BstNode(10);

int main() {

    BinTree b;
    cout << b.Insert(5, root);
    cout<<b.Insert(6, root);
    cout << b.Insert(7, root);
    cout << b.FindMax();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `BinTree::FindMax` and `BinTree::Insert` promise to return values, but don't appear to always make good on the promise. I would address this before continuing.

Comment: It`s hard to got you , can you in another way what i have to correct ?

Comment: Any non-void function should always `return` something. If it doesn't, you have problems.

Comment: I would recommend: 1- going through your program with a debugger. 2- trying to understand recursivity a bit more. 3- writing simpler recursive problems like factorial and fibonnacci sequence before doing this one.

Comment: Your whole program is wrong (where recursivity is used) I was trying to write a solution but I found that I should rewrite most of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to include the comments in your code then others can understand. And I found a lot of bugs in your code.

The first thing to note is if you have a non-void function it should return something.

And `using namespace std;` pollute the namespace.
Hence, use

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

And it is no need to have a separate structure if you are using classes in your file. Try to do implement it inside the class.

And `root == NULL` can be changed as `!root`.

And your Insert function has logical errors.

And if you return something in the if statement no need to use else if, just use if.

And better to use two separate files for the main and the implementation and use it as a header file.

And protect your header files from multiple inclusion.

And bla bla bla...;)

Here I have corrected some of your mistakes. but not all, try to correct them all yourself.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct BstNode
{
    int data;
    BstNode *left;
    BstNode *right;

    BstNode(int data1) : data(data1), left(NULL), right(NULL){};

    ~BstNode(){};
};

class BinTree
{
private:
    BstNode *root;

public:
    BinTree() : root(NULL) {}

    ~BinTree() {}

    BstNode *Insert(int data, BstNode *root)
    {
        if (!root)
        {
            return new BstNode(data);
        }
        if (data > root->data)
        {
            root->right = Insert(data, root->right);
        }
        else
        {
            root->left = Insert(data, root->left);
        }

        return root;
    }

    int FindMax(BstNode *root)
    {
        return MaxHelper(root);
    }

    int MaxHelper(BstNode *root)
    {
        if (!root)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (root->right)
        {
            root = root->right;
        }
        return root->data;
    }

    void Preorder(BstNode *root)
    {
        if (!root)
            return;
        Preorder(root->left);
        cout << root->data << " ";
        Preorder(root->right);
    }
};

int main()
{

    BstNode *root = new BstNode(10);
    BinTree b;
    b.Insert(5, root);
    b.Insert(6, root);
    b.Insert(7, root);
    b.Insert(11, root);
    cout << b.FindMax(root) << endl;
    b.Preorder(root);

    return 0;
}
```